# Two way diode IC?

Tags: diodes, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I'm building a diode network similar to this:

[image]

I'm trying to make the footprint of this circuit as small as possible. In the circuit above, there are 5 "pads" - the top horizontal surfaces. The design requires six pads. Or 12 diodes. Attached is my first attempt (my soldering is terrible):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdT9P.jpg

As you can see, it is incomplete (plus it looks like a spitroast) - there's only six diodes as opposed to twelve. That's because it was getting far too crowded. I want the profile of that pcb to remain as flat as possible, and I'm just not seeing how this is possible with my limited knowledge. Is it?

I'm wondering if there may be integrated circuits that accomplish this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Sir, could you please provide us the honor to know what useful application this circuit will have?

Comment: Something like https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BAV99_SER.pdf ?

Comment: @user287001 is a sensor of kinds. Imagine you have a many of the above circuits with different resistor values. You can use the value of the resistor to identify which PCB was touched with two terminals.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you so much! How do you find such things?!

Comment: I saw it somewhere else and remembered the part number.

Comment: @user253751 any thought of how to route those to a resistor? It will all be in a very small space. Will I have to get a custom PCB created? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accommodate all those diodes in as small of space a possible then you want to use an IC like the DA112S1. The following picture shows the chip configuration.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture From Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/da112s1.pdf)*</sup>

You would connect your resistor between pins 6 and 8.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: @SirPattalot - Be sure to read the data sheet. This type of diode array in a single piece of silicon will not have the same level of reverse voltage rating that a typical discrete diode will have. This particular part is limited to an absolute maximum reverse bias voltage of 18V.

Comment: Keras thanks for the heads up. I'm working with a 5V signal so I exceeding that 18V won't be an issue. Thanks!